# How can I edit set distance result in x axis?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been following [MaxEdge's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TxZBbq8BMA) for making an eye with Geometry Nodes. However, their way only has control over the pupil size, while I also want to be able to make the pupil oval-shaped in a similar way as the iris is done and can't figure out a way to incorporate that function into the nodes myself without it affecting the whole model or having other unintended effects.

My current setup:
[image: Geometry node setup]

Geometry Nodes setup:
[image: UV Sphere with the effect enabled]

[image: UV Sphere edge]

The UV Sphere currently with one end having a tiny hole and extra edge for the effect (with node modifier disabled).

[image]

Comment: you want help from us in our spare time for free, and now you expect us to rebuild everything manually and listen to the yt video? Sorry, but i expect the blend file from you because i am too lazy to rebuild everything manually and/or listening to the whole tutorial.

Comment: I've added the file to the post.

Comment: @Chris, it would be nice if you were a little more welcoming to new visitors. I understand your point of view, but it can be put in a friendlier way. Thank you for your understanding! (...nichts für ungut ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To additionally change the pupil in this setup, you could use the following setup:

[image]

Here I rotate the points in the front lateral area around the center of the sphere in such a way that the spherical shape is retained and at the same time the mesh is not negatively influenced.

I achieve this by processing the dot products of the positions on the X and Y axes.

I use all values on the Y-axis as the basis for this process and limit the effective range with the `Clamp` node.

The intensity or angle, on the other hand, is obtained by multiplying the dot product on the X-axis by a specific value (the intensity of the slit).

Finally, these two values only need to be multiplied together and you get an angle with which you can rotate all points on the Z-axis.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you have various options for additionally influencing the effective range (for example with the math node *Sine* or *Arccosine*, etc.).

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 4.0.2+)*</sub>